# Make zeros of x and y axes common in matplotlib - python (after limiting x axis)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have limited x axis and due to this I get two different zeros for x and y axis, I want to make it common origin and have link drawn from it, please have a look at code and figure -

```
    x=[0 , flow]
    y=[0 , pressure]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlim(0,fr_value[len(fr_value)-1])
    plt.xlabel('Flow Rate')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set ylim

```
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
```

Sample:

```
x=[0 , 8]
y=[0 , 9]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,8)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.xlabel('Flow Rate')
```

[image]